# Are we getting a higher proportion of off-topic questions than other sites?

Tags: discussion

From what I've been seeing, we've had a number of off-topic questions around in the past few days/weeks, such as the recent [What is one word that means to matter less?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/8585/what-is-one-word-that-means-to-matter-less). Now, obviously we have very good processes to close or delete these, but I'm thinking: on other beta sites on which I'm a member, I haven't seen nearly as many off-topic questions per on-topic. So there's the question: are we getting a higher proportion of off-topic questions?

Comment: I haven't had the chance yet to look at the data in detail, but it looks like we are seeing ~10% closure rate on questions. That does not take into account reopenings after questions are fixed to address issues, which lowers the total closed percentage. I would say that's quite acceptable.

Comment: Some people are just really distracted (migrated from here) http://superuser.com/questions/862690/windows-7-gets-hung-when-it-tries-to-load-the-file-classpnp-sys

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing the breakdown on closed questions by closure reason and, for each, the rate of reopening.  My gut feeling is that we get a lot of "too broad" closures that are then fixed and reopened, but I don't have the data (and actually don't know how to get it -- status history isn't in SEDE).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have we had that many really? Completely off topic questions (as opposed to just overly broad) are fairly rare really.

I also have to ask if it matters? If they happen we deal with them. What difference does it make if our ratio is lower or higher than other sites? How is that information useful to us?

The recent ones may be connected to the fact that we get a lot of questions in HNQ so it's not surprising that we get people coming in who are not familiar with what is on or off topic here.

Comment: Just a wonder. I was comparing our stats to other betas and thought of this

Comment: Analytics says we are closing something like one question out of ten. Not sure how many are later reopened though.

Answer (score 1):

I have not done much for beta work other than this and software recommendations.  This site does have more than SR but that is a pretty strait forward topic.  I think this site will always have a little trouble differentiating between on and off topic just as a byproduct of the subject matter.